# Why doesn't The Flash catch fire due to air friction?

Tags: dc, physics, the-flash

What protects The Flash from air friction? At the speed at which he moves, he should be affected by air friction.

Answer (score 2):

[The Flash](http://screenrant.com/wp-content/uploads/The-Flash-Casting-Writing-Interview.jpg)'s super speed comes from his ability to tap into the [Speed Force](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Speed_Force).

While the the Speed Force affects each person differently, in general it shields a speedster from pesky things like air friction.